# Match VAR_NAME but not $(VAR_NAME)

Tags: regex, grep

How can I match `VAR_NAME` but omit `$(VAR_NAME)` at the same time using `grep` or `egrep`? The best attempt so far has been

```
egrep -nH '*[^(]VAR_NAME' $i
```

But this doesn't match the case when the line starts with VAR_NAME. On the other hand, it matches the other occasions correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this doesn't match the case when the line starts with VAR_NAME

So add that case in:

```
egrep -nH '*[^(]VAR_NAME|^VAR_NAME' $i
```

`|` matches either the left pattern or the right pattern. `^` outside of `[]` matches the beginning of a line.

---

Do note that there are other cases that this excludes: `(VAR_NAME)` without a preceding `$` is one. [Toto's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1246055/302463) should match that.

But, even that will miss things cases like `$(VAR_NAME other stuff`, i.e. no closing parenthesis. This may be covered by using `grep` twice:

```
grep -nH 'VAR_NAME' $i | grep -v '$(VAR_NAME)'
```

The first use of grep gets every line that includes `VAR_NAME`, the second, with the `-v` flag, filters the output of the first to *remove* everything that matches `$(VAR_NAME)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) with `-P` flag (Perl regular expression):

```
grep -P '(?<!\$\()VAR_NAME'
```

This will match `VAR_NAME` only when not preceeded by `$(`.

`$` and `(` have to be escaped because they have special meaning in regex.

Answer (score 1):

You need a regex which will match the name anywhere in the line as long as it is not preceeded by a left parenthesis.

The solution to the problem is the following regex:
`'^[^(]*VAR_NAME'`.  This will match VAR_NAME only if the line starts with zero or more non left paren characters.

Note:  This suffices only if there are no left parens on the line before VAR_NAME.  Since the regex you posted does not take this into consideration, I assume that this is not an issue.

Comment: Doesn't work if `VAR_NAME` is not at the begining of line.

Comment: @Toto It worked in all of my test.  It will match zero or more non left paren characters before VAR_NAME, so it will find it anywhere in the line.

Comment: It excludes `(VAR_NAME)` but not `$(VAR) VAR_NAME`